# Has there been a change in how Blazor localization works?

Tags: c#, .net-core, localization, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've been trying to implement resource pages for both English and Norwegian in a Blazor serverside app. I have follow different guides with some different syntax ([Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and an article from [c-sharpcorner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/localization-in-blazor-server/)), but as you can see in the picture at the bottom it still says "welcome" (which is the keyword) when it should say "Hello.". I have the correct imports (according to the docs and guides) and here is my project structure:

[image]

Here is what Startup.cs looks like now:

```
namespace LocalizingTest
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-GB"), 
            new CultureInfo("nb")
        };
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => 
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en-GB");
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseRequestLocalization();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
}
```

And Counter.razor:

```
@page "/counter"

@inject IStringLocalizer<Counter> Translator

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<p>@Translator["welcome"]</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

[image: Counter page where I try to use the "welcome" key from my .resx file]

I can't find any discrepancies between my project and those shown in tutorials/docs, so has anything changed with Blazor server-side localization, or am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: How did you setup the languages in your browser?

Comment: You might want to use the Blazor version of the docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-server

Comment: @HenkHolterman I havent done any setup for the browser; it should still be able to find the value from the default localization file as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#culture-fallback-behavior

Comment: @MisterMagoo Thank you for the suggestion. It references the doc ive already used a lot, but I'll try the cookie and bind:culture that is mentioned (Though I would be surprised if it made any difference)

Comment: Hold onto your hat! 

Comment: @MisterMagoo What do you mean? Do you have a working example? :o

Comment: No, I don't but I have seen it working

Comment: I have pushed a repo to Github showing how this works - https://github.com/SQL-MisterMagoo/BlazorCultures

Answer (score 2):

For others having the same issue. Don't forget to add RequestCultureProviders:

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => 
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en-GB");
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

            // <-- This
            options.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider());
        });
```

AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider changes the culture base on the *accept-language* header. There are also other providers (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.localization.requestcultureprovider).